# Dynamically sql change table name in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

i make this trigger in my db:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mytesttrigger` 
AFTER INSERT ON `x` 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO test (test.y) VALUES (NEW.r)
```

Actually i want from this trigger to add this data into specific table like (test1,test2,etc) depends on NEW.r value. 
    CREATE TRIGGER `mytesttrigger` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `x` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO  (test.y) VALUES (NEW.r)

NOTE: assuming that all tables exists (table1,table2,etc)

Comment: This sounds like a really, really bad application design.  You would need to use dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want, but I cannot recommend this approach.

Comment: yeah i know but i want to learn this for my educational purpose

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` clause can help you doing dynamic SQL.

Assuming your table `X` has only the column `r`

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mytesttrigger` 
AFTER INSERT ON `x` 
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.r = "SOLUTION1" THEN
  SET @query = "insert into TABLE1 values (NEW.r)" ;
ELSIF NEW.r = "SOLUTION2" THEN
  SET @query = "insert into TABLE2 values (NEW.r)" ;
END IF;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: therefore in this example is possible? how can i implement these in my sql statement

Comment: ok that premise us to know solution1,2,... actually as i said i need to create this table name variable like:  if NEW.r is 32 i need to insert data in test32 if NEW.r is 55 i need to insert data in test55 but i dont know 32,55 before